# Check if video is playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I check if video is playing in Unity. I know that when the video is completed, I add a function such as

```
videoPlayer.loopPointReached += CallThisFunction();

public void CallThisFunction(){

}
```

Is there a similar way to check if video has started playing?

Comment: `videoPlayer.isPlaying` from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-isPlaying.html

Answer (score -1):

try using `videoPlayer.isPlaying`

```
if (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.Log("Video is playing");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Video is not playing");
        }
```